# GhostScript removes images from some processed PDF files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm using this command with gs 9.01:

`gs -q -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf in.pdfmarks`

and on some processed files (`out.pdf`) I noticed that images are missing, although present in input file (`in.pdf`).

Why is this and how can I assure that images are retained after processing with gs?

Answer (score 1):

1) Update to the current version, 9.04.

2) If you still experience problems, report a bug at http://bugs.ghostscript.com. You will need to attach a sample PDF file